# How to check what local server is installed in my machine?

Tags: command-line, localhost

How do I know if my machine (Ubuntu) is using some local server? Like wampp, xampp or lampp? And also how do I know my Ubuntu version something like that?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `netstat -atup`

here

```
-t : Select all TCP services
-u : Select all UDP services
-a : Display all listening and non-listening sockets.
-p : Display the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs
```

you will get all the services along with the PID.

Answer (score 3):

Try `nmap localhost` in terminal. It will list all the ports that are being used by some services. 
Example output:

```
ORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

How to check version in terminal:

- Apache2: `apache2 -v`
- PHP: `php -v`
- MySQL: `mysql --version`
- Ubuntu: `lsb_release -a`

Comment: no i dont see any server running. But im sure there is at least one server installed.

Comment: What's the output of nmap?